# is it possible to build a borderless GUI in wxPython snapped to desktop edge?

Tags: wxpython, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to make a desktop application that on which we can store links to application either in PyQt or wxPython, much like mac bar at the bottom or Alienware sidebar...

any reference to begin with would be appreciated... :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with Qt.WindowType and Qt.WindowFlags http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qt.html search for Qt.WindowType and you will see `Qt.WStyle_NoBorder   FramelessWindowHint Use Qt.FramelessWindowHint instead.`
You can set with m`y_window..setWindowFlags(my_window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

even i was also searching for the same. and i would like to share what i found

```
style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.NO_BORDER
```

use this while creating the WX.FRAME and this will help creating the borderless GUI :)